# Relations Symmetric, Reflexive, Transative

Tags: relations

Suppose R1 and R2 are relations on a nonempty set A

1)  If **R1 and R2 are reflexive,** must **R1\R2** be reflexive, symmetric or transitive?

Comment: **Obviously** none of the above.

Comment: What do you think?  It is customary to post your own thoughts on this, so we can provide some focused feedback

Comment: Can you explain each one ?

Comment: I understand intersection and union but I could not solve these